# Overriding spring bean based on bean id and primary attribute

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Lets say I have a spring bean like so in a config file 'A':

`<bean id="foo" class="bar" />`

Then, I have another config file 'B' (which is loaded after 'A') and in it, I have:

`<bean id="foo" class="baz" />`

I have read that the bean in 'B' (with class `baz`) would override the bean in 'A'. But this is brittle. However, what about if I included the `primary="true"` for the bean in 'B' - would this mean that the bean in 'B' would always override the bean in 'A' since it is defined as the primary bean for `id="foo"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are loading the beans with the same ID, the app would have only a single bean (whichever was loaded the last). Using "primary" would have no effect.

Primary tag plays a role when you load multiple beans with the same type and search for a bean using type (and not ID). In this scenario, if you nominate a specific bean as primary, then that bean is returned. If you do not nominate any bean as primary, then you get an error saying multiple beans with the same type have been found (even if the beans were loaded using separate context files).